Aiohttp Ignore Response Headers
I want to get a response from an API using aiohttp.ClientSession().get(), however the API's raw response headers contain an entry that looks something like 'Status Code': 200. This makes aiohttp throw an error because of the space in the name of the header entry.
It says:
Invalid header token:
b('Status Code: 200')
And it points to the space between Status and Code. (I am unable to take a screenshot due to access restrictions)
This is a flaw in the way the API was designed, but unfortunately I do not have access to this API to fix it.
What I'm wondering is if there is any way I can force aiohttp's ClientSession to ignore either this specific header or somehow configure it to accept spaces in header entries.
Is this possible?
I'm running aiohttp version 3.10.5 and python version 3.12.1

create an issue on their repo. sounds like this is related: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/262

I think the server's response is really an invalid token.  The issue report on GitHub, mentioned by Jeremy Fiel, was from 9 years ago.  There was a discussion about it, and the decision was made not to suppress invalid server responses.  So the issue was intentionally not fixed.  Can you just add exception handling to your code?

I need the JSON response from the API and I know it's going to have this malformed header token every single time, so adding exception handling would not really help me at all. I am able to load the JSON response with python's requests.session.get() properly, and I can get the response with a web browser just fine. Isn't there any way I could build out a custom handler to ignore or replace this malformed header token?

the issue does have a recommendation to create a custom parser policy  https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/262#issuecomment-72012967

In short, no. Allowing such headers would lead to HTTP request smuggling vulnerabilities, so both (C and Python) parsers are strict against this.

If you're really desperate, you could maybe monkey patch ResponseHandler._payload.feed_data() and fix the headers before passing the data into the parser: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/26772ad320c1ee0efa5b91ae35ae5860a37cd709/aiohttp/client_proto.py#L280

The docs say that ClientRequest() can take an argument raise_for_custom, that allows you to pass in a custom error handler.  I have no experience with this but it might be what you need.
